# How to support IOS6 and IOS7 app icons and launch images in the same app?

Tags: ios, ios7, icons, coronasdk

How to support IOS6 and IOS7 app icons and launch images in the same app?

I have noted IOS7 has [new Icon sizes pere here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1), however it's not clear to me how you would best ensure IOS 6 and IOS 7 devices are supported?  So how would you do this, e.g.

a) have to put both IOS6 and IOS7 app icon & launch images in?
b) or just put IOS7 icons/launch images in and IOS6 devices will handle this ok?

NOTE: I'm using Corona SDK as my dev platform (not XCode / ObjectiveC)

Comment: Have you read the [iOS Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/design/index.html) document? There's a whole table covering this.

Comment: ok - see the app icons sizes were listed under Human Interface Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) & that they are different.  Can't find however any clarification in terms of if you want to support IOS6 & IOS7 how this works?  i.e. do I need to bundle two sets of icon sizes for IOS6 and IOS7 so my app will work on both?

Comment: Have you looked at the "General" tab for your app's target in Xcode 5? The answer will be clear.

Comment: I'm not using xCode/objectiveC - my development platform is corona sdk

Comment: I'll try to run up Xcode and look for what you're referring to

Comment: It may help if you update your question and/or tags to reflect that you are using the Corona SDK.

Comment: done - have updated tags/text - downloading the xcode seek now - 1.9GB :(   Keen to find out the answer so I know what I should doing with my first app I have just finished. i.e. deploy within a week as is, or try to update with IOS7 icons/launch images etc

Comment: hi @rmaddy - updated the question to be more specific - hopefully this will help

Comment: Have a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this hasn't been answered, this page covers it all:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/17/tutorial-getting-started-with-ios-7/

Comment: Apparently they fixed it. I just got an error when i tried yesterday.