# Launch screens supporting iOS6 and iOS7 - forced to splash screen

Tags: ios7, splash-screen

When it comes to the launch screen I can't find a unifying way to mimic the look of the application on both iOS6 and iOS7 (supporting both). Are we forced to make a regular splash screen of a logo or similar if we have a toolbar menu or do you guys have any great ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

### Short answer

In iOS 7, an app can use a different launch image depending on which version of iOS it’s running in. To provide different launch images, add the **UILaunchImages** key to the Info.plist file and use a dictionary to describe each launch image.

### Background

It uses the following keys:

> **UILaunchImageName** - A string containing the name of the PNG image file. The image file must reside at the top level of the app bundle.
>   The name you specify for this key should not include a filename
>   extension, nor should it include modifiers such as @2x, -568h,
>   ~iphone, or ~ipad.
>
> On disk, your image filenames may still include the @2x, -568h,
>   ~iphone, or ~ipad modifiers as appropriate, although they are not
>   required. The system automatically accounts for such modifiers when
>   choosing which file to load.
>
> **UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion** - for iOS7 this should be a string “7.0”.
>
> **UILaunchImageOrientation** – String containing one of: Portrait, PortraitUpsideDown, Landscape, LandscapeLeft, LandscapeRight.
>
> **UILaunchImageSize** – *String* specifying width and height, ex: “{320, 480}”. You must specify the width and height with respect to
>   the device in a portrait orientation. In other words, portrait and
>   landscape images targeting the same device would have the same width
>   and height.
>
> If this key is present, iOS 7 uses it exclusively to obtain launch
>   images.

BUT: I found that sticking to the naming convention also for iOS7 helped a lot!

> This key is supported in iOS 7.0 and later.

### OK – so now what?

Because I already had launch images for iOS6 and with all their specific naming conventions. I chose to make a copy of all of them and prefix the name with ”iOS7-” so as to limit my own confusion about all the different sizes and names. Making a prefix should prove to come in handy as then most of the images would immediately be loaded correctly.

The filenames:
I had these for iOS6 already, I also list the file sizes for those in need:

- Default.png `(320x480)`
- Default@2x.png `(640x960)`
- Default@2x~ipad.png `(2048x1496)`
- Default~ipad.png `(768x1004)`
- Default1024x768.png `(1024x768)`
- Default1024x768@2x.png `(2048x1536)`
- Default-568h@2x.png `(640x1136)`
- Default768x1024.png `(768x1024)`
- Default768x1024@2x.png `(1536x2048)`
- Default-Landscape~ipad.png `(1024x748)`
- Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png `(1536x2048)`

So I made a copy of all of these filenames for iOS7 (same sizes) prefixing them with "iOS7-":

- iOS7-Default.png
- iOS7-Default@2x.png
- ...

### In XCode

Now to create your entry in PLIST. Go to your-name-of-application.plist. In a blank area, right-click and choose ”Add Row”. Make sure it becomes a top item and not a sub-item of some other information in the .plist.

Write:
`UILaunchImages`

Right-click on this UILaunchImages and select value type ”Array”.

Use the illustration below as a guide to the text and for how it will look when it is all finished:

[image]

If you open up this array so the little indicator triangle to the left points down, it is empty the first time, but if you choose ”add row” while it is open it will create a sub-line. Do that now:

Right-click on the UILaunchImages and select ”Add row”.
Right-click on this new line (item 0) and select value type ”Dict”

Continue opening this items with the triangle indicator and right-click and ”Add row”

This item you will name `UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion` and set value type to “string” and the string to “7.0”

Now the following are all strings and should be at the same level as the UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion item. In the same dict (dictionary). Create these by just choosing “Add row” for each:

`UILaunchImageName` – base-name-of-iOS7-launch-image. In my case this was ”iOS7-Default”

`UILaunchImageOrientation` - example: Portrait

`UILaunchImageSize` - the size of the elementary base iOS7-Default.png: "{320, 480}". The program will find all the files with permutations of the base name. Remember to select the base name of the file without ipad/iphone/portrait/landscape or .png specifications.

**Note:**

Xcode had already made the following items in the .plist for me after first adding iOS6 images in all available slots :-)

UILaunchImageFile~ipad … = ”Default” – so this was OK

UILaunchImages~ipad … Had two items that needed to be updated to iOS7 versions, because they where now incorrectly holding the iOS6 version. Those I had named Default1024x768 and Default768x1024 and now I just prefixed ”iOS7-” to each of the names and I was done.

### Example of how it may look for those wanting to edit plist directly:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
      <string>7.0</string>
      <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
      <string>iOS7-Default </string>
      <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
      <string>Portrait</string>
      <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
      <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

[edit by jd: fixed spelling of "UILaunchImages"]

Comment: UILaunchImage for orientation for landscape should be in the form "Landscape (right home button)" style, not "LandscapeRight". As of 7.0.2 / Xcode 5.0 there appears to be a bug that iOS7 landscape images cannot be used if iOS6 images are present.

Comment: I want to  add  the new multitasking support in my app, so I should replace the launch images with launch screen, and it works well in iOS 8.0 and later, but as you know,  the launch screen does not support iOS 7,  when I run it on iOS 7 device(4s) ,  black screen comes. I did as you said, but unfortunately it did not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Highlight the project in the project browser, select "General", scroll down to "App Icons", click on "Use Asset Catalog", and select "Migrate". Your existing icons and splash screens will be automagically migrated into an asset catalog.  You can then select the catalog to add further images.

To add new images you simply drag from Finder and drop into the squares for each image type.

(Caution:  The catalog editor inexplicably uses a non-scrollable wide format, and you can be missing stuff off the right side if your screen isn't wide enough.)

Comment: You just explained asset catalog in such a way that I understand it very easily. I'm now using asset catalog and I'm very impressed with this functionality.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer - Yeah, it's pretty cryptic to start with -- I was tempted to not use it.  But once I got it going it seems fairly simple and straight-forward, at least for the basic cases.

Comment: I was eager to use it, but reading other tutorials and Apple's, I didn't realize what it id. I don't understand why they made it so complicated, once I read your explanation. I enabled it.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer - Yeah, it seems like the purpose of much Apple documentation is to obscure and confuse.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the new [image catalogue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) feature in Xcode 5 to manage multiple versions of launch images.

Comment: But how do you convince the app to make use of the image catalog?

Comment: Never mind -- figured it out.  Highlight the project in the project browser, select "General", scroll down to "App Icons", click on "Use Asset Catalog", and select "Migrate".  It's all done automagically.

Comment: How do you localise an image that is inside a catalog? (I am talking about the launch image)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can directly add the app icons and splash images in the images.xcassets,
Click on + button to add the respective image set for iphone5 with iOS 5,6,7 ,iphone4, iPad.
now no need to set the images name like default.png,default@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

Be warned when using an images.xcassets repository it will not allow you to localize your splash screens.

I'm currently trying to get a French and English version of our app.

WWW> Will this 'plist' method work if you need to localize your splash screens?

Comment: I know it's probably not relevant now but for anyone else looking at this question, the iOS design guidelines explicitly tell you you're not going to be able to localize the text in the LaunchImage.



    Text. The launch image is static, so any text you display in it won’t be localized.


Source:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with an older app that I developed for iOS 7.  It Archived and Uploaded fine with Xcode 6, but the "binary not optimized for iPhone5" error returned with Xcode 7.  After trying a myriad of other solutions, I was only successful by removing all references to any Launch Image (since I was using a universal .xib) AND setting the deployment target from 7.0 to 8.0