# Xcode launch image issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 5.0.2 and am trying to use asset catalog for the launch image. 
I have iPhone 2x and R4 selected. I am trying the to drag and drop image for the launch image but no success.

here are the png resolutions I tried

320 by 480
640 by 960
640 by 1136.

none of them, i am able to drag and drop anywhere in the asset catalog for the image.

(I deleted the default images)

Is this an Xcode bug ? Or...

Is there any file naming convention to be used like "default"?

Comment: solved it by using the default name!!!                here is post to see the default name. you can rename your files and use them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976412/launch-screens-supporting-ios6-and-ios7-forced-to-splash-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a convention for naming your launch images.

Either you can specify filename via `UILaunchImage` field in Info.plist file of your project.
As a value, filename of your launch image should be specified.

If you don't add this field to Info.plist file, then you have to use `Default.png` filename for your launch images (with appropriate postfix).

[Reference from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12).

P.S. here's a useful note regarding custom filenames for launch image:

> Note: If you are using the UILaunchImageFile key in your Info.plist file to specify a custom base name for your launch image files, add device-specific versions as needed to differentiate the launch images on different devices. For example, specify a UILaunchImageFile~ipad key to specify a different base name for iPad launch images. Specifying different base names lets a universal app avoid naming conflicts among its launch images. For more information on how to apply device modifiers to keys in the Info.plist file, see Information Property List Key Reference.

(c) [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW18)

Comment: thank you that was it. Just had to rename my files to the default name and then just drag them there.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the image is in the right dimension and is a `PNG` file instead of a `JPG` file. As art-diving said, also use the correct names. Follow the guide on [Apple's page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12).