# Can't submit the app with storyboard launch images to the App Store: Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: xcode, ios8, storyboard, xcode6, launchimage

I am trying to submit my first app to the App Store but when I try I am getting the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New
>   iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display
>   on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the
>   info.plist under UILaunchImage with a UILaunchImageSize value set to
>   {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the
>   top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you
>   localize your launch images.

I'm using SDK 8.1. Deployment target is 8.0. Launch images are set by storyboard launch screen file. There is no obsolete launch screen images and I don't plan to add them because target system is iOS 8+.

What is wrong? Xcode version 6.1 (6A1052d).

Comment: Can you observe that iPhone 5 or iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+'s native resolution is used when you are testing on simulator or device?

Comment: Yes, all is right on simulator and on the devices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rename storyboard launch screen file to 'LaunchScreen.storyboard'.

If you create a new Launch Screen file using File -> New -> File, Xcode will default the name to 'Launch Screen.storyboard'.

However, the default name specified in your Info.plist when creating a new project is 'LaunchScreen.storyboard' without the space.

Comment: This is not required. Apple supports both .storyboard and .xib.

Comment: This! I've been struggling with this issue for days, and it was exactly this that resolved it. Fantastic!

Comment: I had this exact issue.  Apple kept rejecting the binary with "Launch Screen" in the info.plist.  Renaming without a space resolved it.

Comment: Please know that according to Apple's update, starting April 2020, apps submitted to the App Store must use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01132020b)

Answer (score 41):

Does your app support iOS7 or previous? That's the issue. In that case you have to provide the splash screen as PNG files for iOS7.

LaunchScreen.xib or LaunchScreen.storyboard only works with iOS8 onwards.

Further information here: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

> With iOS 8, you can now provide an Interface Builder document and, at
>   runtime, have the OS generate all of the necessary Launch Images for
>   you.

Comment: This is the exact answer I am looking for. My app's first version only supports IOS8 so I don't have Launch Images. Now I want to support IOS7  and meet this problem....Thank you.

Comment: That's the answer, people should take this answer as the right one

Comment: As of today, React Native had selected 7.0 as its deployment target. Didn't notice it, and was getting very angry. Thanks for this!

Comment: Thumps up dude.. Thanks a lottt

Answer (score 14):

Here is what worked for me after getting mad for 2 days:

1. Set Deployment Target to 7.0
2. Add a new splash image of size **320x568** and name it as **Default-568h.png**.
3. Add the below code in your Info.plist file.

```xml
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

**Points To Ponder**

- My App was completely in Landscape Mode but I had to use this Portrait sized image of the size given above.
- I had to use 320x568 size which is (1x) although every other resource on my project was retina based i.e (2x)
- One more thing: I did not used Asset Catalogues for Launch Images. I was using a custom sequence of splash screens via my code but still I had to follow above steps to get through this error.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had to rotate all my iPhone launch images to the left and specify portrait as orientation, although the whole app is landscape. Before, it was only an iPad app and it worked fine with only the landscape launch images.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error when trying to submit when I was **NOT** using a launch screen xib file. I had all the right image assets at the right dimensions but still no.

I found [this post](https://forum.xojo.com/21558-error-itms-90096-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5/0) where a chap had the same issue and ended up using a 568x320 file as indicated in the error. I tried the same but this didn't work for me.

In the end, as my app is for iOS8 only, I used a xib file and the app submitted successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens because you don't add launch image whose size is 640x1136 (iphone 5) correctly.

After editing Contents.json below, I can upload to iTunesConnect normally

```
{
  "images" : [
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "splash-480h.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "1x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "splash-480h@2x.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "filename" : "splash-568h@2x.png",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "subtype" : "retina4",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "736h",
  "filename" : "splash-736h@3x.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "3x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "736h",
  "filename" : "splash-landscape-736h@3x.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "landscape",
  "scale" : "3x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "667h",
  "filename" : "splash-667h@2x.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "filename" : "splash-480h@2x.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "scale" : "2x"
},
{
  "extent" : "full-screen",
  "idiom" : "iphone",
  "subtype" : "retina4",
  "filename" : "splash-568h@2x.png",
  "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
  "orientation" : "portrait",
  "scale" : "2x"
}
   ],
  "info" : {
"version" : 1,
"author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html it says that iPhone 6(plus) require launch XIB or storyboard file.

And if you have a look here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2 it refers the image sizes and never explicitly says that iPhone 5 can handle a launch file (I know it also does not say that it doesn't). At least iPhone 4s looks like it does not, so I guess that iPhone 5 doesn't either and you have to add a static file.

Comment: @Altaveron Actually that is good to hear. So you mean that it only depends on the name of the launch storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

For the lost Xamarin souls here, I had this issue by using an images xcassets called Images.xcassets under the Resources folder.

I create it from scratch, name it Media.xcassets as it comes from default, and under the root folder, not Resources. And it works. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React Native, and got this problem after adding [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) plugin

However, I got the solution after following the method via this link

[Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856990/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5/46559171#46559171)

The problem has solved when I do this:

1. I have removed laungh images' xcassets totally
2. added the launch image set
3. and added all launch images again
4. created a new ipa again

and this time its successfuly submitted.