# Error ITMS-90096: Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: xcode, asset-catalog

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Looking in the LaunchImage.launchimage folder I have a `Default-568h@2x.png` but not a `Default-568h.png` image.

There doesn't seem to be a space for one so how do I add one to this Asset Catalog?

Comment: Any thoughts on this error when you want to deploy ONLY for iPad form factor?

Comment: @snow Crash your issue solved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to clear "Launch screen file" at "App icons and Launch images"

[image]

Comment: I've been stuck on this for days. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: This issue has a lot of other reasons.

Comment: I only had a launch screen specified because it gave me retina 4 resolutions even though I had both the new launch images available. Took this out and it looks like it's still retina 4. Unfortunately I'm still getting this error from apple for some reason.

Comment: For Retina 4 you have to provide launchimages 640*960 as @2x & 640*1136 as -568h@2x

Comment: If I could give you more points I would... Stuck on this issue for more than an hour. Sometimes it feels like the submission process was made like this just to make a programmer's life impossible :)

Comment: Excuse me, where is App icons and Launch images ?

Comment: Hmm this is on properties, now I have seen.

Comment: Thanks! This answer along with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960203/2361851 answer did the trick for me!

Comment: @Vlad, I am using LaunchScreen.storyboard in my project for Splash screen. And I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a LaunchScreen.xib so I shouldn't have needed the PNG. It turns out that somehow I had deleted it from "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phases. Added it again and Apple accepted the build.

Comment: What a huge waste of time researching iPhone5 HIG and launch screen reqs when the problem was that the xib was not in the copy resources step.  Thanks for posting.  That was a head scratcher

Answer (score 3):

From iOS9, you should add launch images to your project root, not `Images.xcassets` folder. And set your launch images in `info.plist` with key [`UILaunchImages`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28), for my example:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.1</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>iPhone5Portrait</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.1</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>iPhone6Portrait</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message.

the fix was to **check all the warning of xcode** 7.3 during after a clean of the project.

You need to check that all the launchImage have the "correct" and precise resolution.

If one image present in launchImage folder is not with the uncorrect resolution , Apple reject the binary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use an Image Catalog because my app has multiple targets with different resources for each, so simply copying the -568h PNG file into the root directory was not an option.

For those of you using image assets, the following worked for me, give it a try:

On your LaunchImage image assests, open the right hand pane where the devices and OS's that you target are listed as shown here:

[image]

Ensure that you have both these iPhone options selected and that you have loaded the correct size image for both as indicated at the bottom as "**Expected Size**".

Answer (score 0):

set “deployment target” value 7.0