# Has error of ITMS-900096 when upload the app to itunesconnect

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have checked the solution of stackoverflow or follow the error instruction, but still cannot fix this error. Is there any missing look out? For more info, Main is a storyboard. Is it make the submission failed? There is a screen captures at the below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it the bug of xcode?

Comment: Is it possible that your launch images are incorrect sizes?

Comment: when i archive, it does not show any error about incorrect size of launch images

Comment: I would check them anyway. Once you've done that, and the issue isn't resolved, we can try something else.

Comment: I found the same error by this link. I think it helps you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830013/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-itms-90096-when-submitting

Comment: I have tried, but not work for me when i am using the old xcode. After reinstall xcode and migrate this project to new project, this solution is worked. Thank you so much.