# Xcode IMS 90096 Error While App Submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I have an app working fine on all iphone sizes devices properly. I am trying to upload it to app store. I am using LaunchScreen.xib and not using launch images. I have added it to copy bundle resources to solve the problem but it didn't help.

Also solutions mentioned in other questions didn't help me. The error is like below. Anybody has idea about that error?

[image]

Comment: It is not duplicate because i specified that i dont use launch images. I use LaunchScreen.xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already asked before many times.

as mention in this link

[“Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5” (ITMS-90096) when submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830013/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-itms-90096-when-submitting)

> 1. Check all those images are .PNG
> 2. Put those images at root level of your project
> 3. Add another splash.png with name "Default-568h@2x.png" for iPhone 5. Its size should be 640 × 1136 pixel.

Ultimately you need to check your images "all are must be in PNG format".

Edit:

[image]

Comment: I dont use images for launch. Inuse xib for that.

Comment: just check your images. and also check that what you have selected in appicon and lunch images.

Comment: As I told I dont have any launch images neither png nor jpg. all app icons are png and correct.

Comment: can you upload you this portion ? see edited image.

Comment: I have solved by adding "Default-568h@2x.png" for iPhone 5 and size should be 640 × 1136 pixel.

Comment: yeh. this type of issue generally comes with such type of silly mistakes in asset catalog or splash screen. so, when this error comes we have to search all image's format and iconize and image size in assets.