# ITMS-90096 error when submiting Cordova app that uses Launch storyboard image

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a Cordova (6.5.0) app that uses a [single-image launch screen](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#supported-platforms) called `Default@2x~universal~anyany.png`, as per the documentation. That application is **targeting iOS 7.1**.

When I upload to the store, I get an `ITMS-90096` error (Your binary is not optimised for iPhone 5) as can be seen [in another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830013/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-itms-90096-when-submitting).

When targeting iOS 8.0 or above, the error disappear.

How can I get this to work using Cordova? I would like to continue targeting iOS 7.1+ and yet be able to use a Launch storyboard image so that I can benefit from multitasking (split view) on devices that support it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into a very simular issue (same error code) with cordova.
Previous version of my app were fine, however when we pushed an update we got the above error.

I fixed it by converting all the spash images from *.jpg to *.png

Our deployment device was set to 6.0

Answer (score 0):

My app was generated long time ago from VS2015 Cordova project, which somehow have a few res/screens/ios image files not using the correct sized images.  After I compare them with a new VS2017 generated project images, I have to change 4 images accordingly. Then everything went fine.