# xcode: can't upload app to store because of app Icon error

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, xcode8

I want to upload my app to the store but i have this problem:
[image]

this is the app general properties image:
[image: app general properties]

this is the `.scassets` image:
[image]

and this is the `Contents.json` :

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-20x20@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-20x20@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-29x29@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-29x29@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-40x40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-40x40@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-60x60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-60x60@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-20x20@1x.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "20x20",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-20x20@2x-1.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-29x29@1x.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-29x29@2x-1.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-40x40@1x.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-40x40@2x-1.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-76x76@1x.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-76x76@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "83.5x83.5",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

when i run in simulator(Iphone 5 and other), i found that it works correctly and set app icon correctly.
all sizes in the correct size.
what should i do to solve this problem please!!

Comment: do you any image in launch screen storyboard ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28830203/8432814 please check this answer.

Comment: @HakikatSingh I have Launchscreen.xib file but i font ude it

Comment: please check the above link its for the same issue you have posted.

Comment: it is about splash screen not icon

Comment: yes i understand, the answer is about the launch screen please read carefully :)

Comment: The problem in launch screen , you should set all launch screen sizes, you will find it in Assets.xcassets->LaunchImage

Comment: @Hosny yes this is the problem what are the all sizes of splash screen

Comment: You can upload your splash screen to online site like that http://apetools.webprofusion.com/tools/imagegorilla  and get all them

Comment: I think the error message is clear about the missing __splash-screen__ not the app-icon _(but you need to add the 1024x1024 iTunes artwork to your app as well)_.

Answer (score 2):

in scassets file there is no icon for appstore. you have to use 1024 by 1024 imge in appstore icon in scassets.it may the issue

Comment: I have an same issue i have to set 1024 x 1024 app icon in Assets.xcassets and my issuse solved .