# Why do I get this error when publishing from xcode to app store... ITMS-90096

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to publish an archive to the app store using xcode. The build succeeds with some minor errors in image resolution. However, publishing fails with this message regarding compatibility with the iphone 5:

ERROR ITMS-90096 your binary is not optimized for iphone 5

Researching the problem, I found a possible workaround... I added UILaunchImages with UILaunchImageSize default image and size to the key which added this text to my info.plist file:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I also added the file Default-568.png to the images.xcassets folder.

I am at a loss... Anyone have this issue before?

Comment: Here is similar issue - look at these solutions. May it solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28830013/5638630