# iOS Archive upload failed Due to UILaunchImage for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

I need a help with something. I am trying to upload my ios app to Apple Test Flight for beta testing, during the uploading phase I get a validation error, stating that

> Your Binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone app must support 4 - inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referred in info.plist under UILaunchImages.. "

[image: Error message]

But I am using the Launch Screen not the launch image. My plist only have Launch screen interface file base name.. How I can get rid of this error...

Comment: Did you check your General Settings to make sure that Launch Screen File are filled instead of Launch Image Source in `App Icons and Launch Images` ?

Comment: set your Launch screen storyboard under Project -> Target -> General -> App icon and launch image file -> launch sceen file. Here set your launch screen storyboard.

Comment: It should make entry in your .plist "Launch screen interface file base name". If not then add this in your .plist and as value set your launch screen stryboard name there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link --> http://dannysu.com/2014/04/16/not-optimized-for-iphone5/

It looks like you need to specifically assign devices to your launch image/xib.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher, But I am using the Launch Screen not the launch image. My plist only have Launch screen interface file base name.. How I can get rid of this error... I mentioned this at end of my question already.

Comment: What is the name of your Launch Screen file?

Comment: Launch Screen.storyboard

Comment: Change this to LaunchScreen.storyboard (no space)

Comment: Still No Luck. Changed the file Name, then Updated the same in the target, also verified this change in info.plist..

Comment: Try this --> https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39400/error-itms-90096-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5

Comment: Found this one with help of my friend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136053/cant-submit-the-app-with-storyboard-launch-images-to-the-app-store-your-binary

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Set your Launch screen storyboard.

Go to `Project -> Target -> General -> App icon and launch image file -> launch sceen file`

There set your launch screen storyboard file.It will look like below.

[image]

[image]

It should make entry in your .plist  as "`Launch screen interface file base name`". if it is not then add this in your info plist. it should look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot Wolverine, but I did exact things already as if you see the end of my question.

Comment: Still appreciate your efforts.Kudos to that