# Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, app-store, xamarin-studio

I get this error message while submiting my Xamarin.IOS application to App Store.

> ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images.

I have already removed alpha channed and removed transparency from 4-inch launch image on iTunes Connect.

But do I have to remove the alpha channel from every launch image that I have submitted to `iTunes Connect` and even also from all `launch images that I have selected in xcassets on Xamarin Studio` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has solved when I do this :

1. I have removed launge images' xcassets totally
2. added the launch image set and
   added all launch images again
3. created a new ipa again and

and this time its successfuly submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include suggested sizes in your project. It has nothing to do with Itune connect.