# launch screen specifically for iphone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I am creating an app and using the LaunchScreen.storyboard file to create launch screens. I have used to screen class sizes to determine whether the app is running on an iPad or an iPhone and the launch screens appear great. However, one the iPhone 4, where the aspect ratio is different, the launch screen appears distorted. As such, I need to be able to identify when an iPhone 4 is using the app and launch a different launch screen image. My question is this:

Since we only have regular and compact classes, how can I use them to differentiate between an iPhone 4 (3.5 inch) and all the other iPhones?

Is there any work around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976412/launch-screens-supporting-ios6-and-ios7-forced-to-splash-screen) has worked for me although it uses the old ways of creating separate images for each device instead of the LaunchScreen.storyboard file, so it is not the answer I was hopping for, but it does work.